# ocelot change configuration without restarting app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ocelot

I'm trying to change ocelot configuration without restarting app and I don't want use Consul.
Trying to search simple solution.
What I'm trying.

Registered configuration file as `reloadOnChange:true`

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                   .AddJsonFile("configuration.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                   .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }
```

And added Configuration as Singleton

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
```

Also writed service which gives me ability change this singleton configuration using service.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class XBConfigurationController : Controller
    {
        public XBConfigurationController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration as IConfigurationRoot;
        }

        private readonly IConfigurationRoot _configuration;

        // GET: /<controller>/
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            _configuration.Reload();
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

What's wrong? Why ocelot not refreshing it's internal configuration?

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem using administration api.

```
services.AddOcelot(Configuration).AddPolly().AddAdministration("/administration", "secret");
```

And added base url to ocelot configuration file.

```
 "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "RequestIdKey": "OcRequestId",
    "AdministrationPath": "/administration",
    "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:54864"
  }
```

After changing code followed by this steps

1. Generate token using this service `http://localhost:54864/administration/connect/token`
2. Get current configuration using this api `http://localhost:54864/administration/configuration`  with `Get` method and `Bearer Token`
3. Set modified configuration as json input to this api `http://localhost:54864/administration/configuration`

Additional info you can get

[ocelot.postman_collection.json](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/blob/46132b6fa8c50961b39255174a86961d7f91cf6f/postman/ocelot.postman_collection.json)

[Ocelot Administration Api Documentation](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/administration.html)